# Interface for controlling Mac via android

Tags: android

I'm interested in writing a mobile application for android and a remote desktop client for near-range control of a Mac personal computer. All the current implementations I can find make use of UDP over WiFi, and that requires the computer to be on the same WiFi network as the phone. Does anyone know of another interface I could potentially look into to making this work? i.e. Bluetooth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of several ways of communicating between Android - Mac:

1. **Data via remote server** - advantage here is that Android would be able to control Mac even when not on WiFi. But potential security risks are bigger (how to pair the devices?). If your Mac has public IP, it can act as a remote server.
2. **Local WLAN** - using private IP addresses. It's probably easier to make it safe than no. 1, but the Android device would have to be connected to the same WiFi/LAN as Mac.
3. **Bluetooth** - BT would have to be enabled in the Android device which impacts battery life. Lower range than with WLAN.
4. **Sound** - it's underestimated in my opinion. Your Android device would emit tones in a range above approx. 18kHz, Mac would use mic to listen and act accordingly. Advantage: Android can be off WLAN and off data connection. Mac can be offline as well. Disadvantage: unless your use case is simple, implementation of the protocol over this interface would be more troublesome. I did some Android-Android interface this way and it worked better than I expected.

As for the underlying protocol, it depends on your use case. If you plan to implement a remote control, not to stream media etc., I would go with TCP instead of UDP for obvious reasons (reliability mostly, which translates to easier implementation).